# Meltano: (tag and tagret: postgresql) temporary file size exceeds temp_file_limit

Tags: postgresql, airflow, meltano

I'm getting the issue while running **Meltano** with tag and target "postgresql" as source database, without changing the **temp_file_limit** params by the tap "postgresql".
how could I fix that?

`psycopg2.errors.ConfigurationLimitExceeded: temporary file size exceeds temp_file_limit (13411002kB)`

Meltano **meltano.yml** setting file looks like that:

```
default_environment: dev
project_id: fake-id
plugins:
  extractors:
  - name: tap-postgres
    variant: transferwise
    pip_url: pipelinewise-tap-postgres
  - name: tap-google-analytics
    variant: meltanolabs
    pip_url: pip install git+https://github.com/MeltanoLabs/tap-google-analytics.git
  loaders:
  - name: target-postgres
    variant: transferwise
    pip_url: pipelinewise-target-postgres
    config:
      schema_mapping:
        schema_1:
          target_schema: replica_schema_1  
      default_target_schema: public
    
  orchestrators:
  - name: airflow
    pip_url: psycopg2 apache-airflow==2.1.2 --constraint https://raw.githubusercontent.com/apache/airflow/constraints-2.1.2/constraints-${MELTANO__PYTHON_VERSION}.txt
  files:
  - name: airflow
    pip_url: git+https://gitlab.com/meltano/files-airflow.git

schedules:
- name: schedule-name
  extractor: tap-postgres
  loader: target-postgres
  transform: skip
  interval: '*/30 * * * *'


environments:

- name: dev
  config:
    plugins:
      extractors:
      - name: tap-postgres
        config:
          dbname: $TAP_POSTGRES_DBNAME
          user: $TAP_POSTGRES_USER
        
        select:
        - schema_name-table_name_1
        - schema_name-table_name_2

      loaders:
      - name: target-postgres
        config:
          user: $TARGET_POSTGRES_USER
          dbname: $TARGET_POSTGRES_DBNAME
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? Currently your question reads as "I'm having error.. How to fix?"

Comment: here is the issue:
```psycopg2.errors.ConfigurationLimitExceeded: temporary file size exceeds temp_file_limit (13411002kB)```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the database flag to Postgres `temp_file_limit` to something higher like 10mb I think it is binary so 10485760. If you run this off a replica then add the `temp_file_limit` but also add `max_standby_archive_delay` and `max_standby_streaming_delay` to like 900s.